# Component VaR is additive but at what level

Tags: value-at-risk, statistical-finance

I have a portfolio data as

```
Account     Symbol      ComponentVaR
Acc1        MSFT        CV1
Acc2        GOOG        CV2
Acc1        FUT1        CV3
Acc2        FUT2        CV4
```

So, are following calculations correct.

```
Account     ComponentVaR
Acc1        CV1+CV3
Acc2        CV2+CV4
```

And portfolio VaR can be CV1+CV2+CV3+CV4

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no :-)

Portfolio VaR = CV1 + CV2 + CV3 + CV4 is correct.

To safeguard my answer, I looked this up from [thinxlabs.com](http://thinxlabs.com/blog/finance/incremental-var-component-var/)

> The individual component VaRs from the assets in the portfolio should add up tho the total portfolio VaR. The equation is as follows.

But you need to calculate another VaR for each account, if you want to use CV on those. The reason is that the asset weight, is not the same for a given asset when you look at a subset of the portfolio.